# how to use API on flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to use this api https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/ on flutter
can someone give me an example of how to use it

thanks

Comment: yes (if you can) i'm new on flutter

Comment: This [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/1rXFKhBZXxY) could be of help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use http package. Official docs are always the best source: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Full example in the linked website, however there's the most crucial code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```